# Flutter BLOC listener receive same state multiple times

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a list and on clicking any item of that list I am removing that item from the list and calculating the clicked count.

For the 1st item its working perfectly, for the second item the same state called twice and for the 3rd thrice (continuing...).

Code Below. Thanks in advance for helping me out!

```
thisBloc.stream.listen((state) {
      if (state is AnswerSubmitFailed) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(state.message),
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
            ),
          );
        });
      }
      if (state is AnswerSubmitSuccess) {
        var answeredQuestion = widget.section.questions
            .where((e) =>
                e.sectionId == state.sectionId && e.id == state.questionId)
            .firstOrNull;
        //, orElse: () => null
        if (answeredQuestion != null) {
          setState(() {
            widget.section.questions.remove(answeredQuestion);
            answeredCount += 1;
          });
        }
      }
      if (state is OnProgress) {
        context.loaderOverlay.show();
      } else {
        context.loaderOverlay.hide();
      }
    });
```